Generating Context Free Grammar where the ith character matches the character at i+3
I'm having trouble generating context-free grammar where the characters are 0 or 1 and the symbol at position i is the same as the symbol at position i+3 and the string is greater than 4.
L : {x ∈ {0, 1}∗ | the symbol at position i is the same as the symbol at position i+3, |x| ≥ 4}
I was able to genearate all strings that are 4 characters long to follow the language but I have not been able to go beyond when the length is 4

Interestingly, a CFG is overkill here. A regular expression would be enough, though a lot of possibilities have to be listed (line breaks here are ORs):
000 0+
0 (010)+ (0 | 01)?
0 (100)+ (1 | 10)?
0 (110)+ (1 | 11)?
1 (001)+ (0 | 00)?
1 (011)+ (0 | 01)?
1 (101)+ (1 | 10)?
111 1+

A CFG could then be constructed based on this regular expression. Recreating just the second line above as a CFG:
S -> 0 A B

A -> 010 A
A -> 010

B -> ε
B -> 0
B -> 01

This is not a particularly efficient or inspired creation, but I believe the result is correct.
